# Google play leaderboard shows only me

Tags: android, google-play-services

I implemented leaderboard in one of my apps but it shows just me, multiple of my friends have played it, but none of them were displayed on the leaderboard.
All of them did connect to google play games.

Help me find what I am doing wrong.

I call this once in my main activity. The apiClient is static variable

```
apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to connect to google play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .build();
    apiClient.connect();
```

And the following piece of code is called everytime a use returns to the level selection activity after completing a level:

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks cb;

cb = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(MainActivity.apiClient,
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_most_stars),
                    totalStars);
            MainActivity.apiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(cb);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }
    };

MainActivity.apiClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(cb);
```

It works just perfect for me, I tested on two accounts, both were listed on leaderboard. If it's a coding error, then even I should not be there either.

I checked the leaderboard and game is published in play console, however, the console has a wierd alert that says achievements are not implemented properly, but I never have included any achievements at all. Probably unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

In [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/), check if you actually published the **Game Services**, it doesn't automatically publish when you publish the game itself.

Easy to happen if you are in the Testing phase, so your account is included as tester but not your friends, so you are the only one with access to the leaderboard.